# Can not upload certain files in PHP

Tags: php, html

I have an issue in image file upload when uploading certain files.

```
<form method="POST" action="upload.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileupload">
    <input type="submit" name="fileSubmit" value="fileSubmit">
</form>
```

In my PHP file I tried to output the `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]` array
but this was the result:

```
Array
(
    [name] => CIMG6223.JPG
    [type] => 
    [tmp_name] => 
    [error] => 1
    [size] => 0
)
```

`$_FILES["fileToUpload"][tmp_name]` was empty. I think some error occured in my uploading, but when I tried to upload another file, it could upload that file and there was value in `$_FILES["fileToUpload"][tmp_name]`. In my `php.ini` file, I changed `post_max_size` and `upload_max_filesize` to `100M`, but I couldn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be checking for errors:

> 1 = UPLOAD_ERR_INI_SIZE Value: 1; The uploaded file exceeds the
>   upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini.

rtm: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

**Did you restart Apache?**

Comment: thanks for reply...i have increased maximum file size that we can upload in php.ini file.. but still exists the issue...

Comment: Did you restart apache or php-fpm whichever your using? Also do a `<php phpinfo()` and check its using the correct php.ini and has the value you want 100M

Comment: problem solved when i restarted apache... thank u for your help.

Comment: np, glad to help